# C# MessageBox with DialogResult giving "No overload for method 'Show' takes '3' arguments"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, messagebox, dialogresult

I am developing an application for Windows CE using Visual Studio 2008.

Code:

```
    private void cmdLogOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        if (loginStatus == false)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "text", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //Do Stuff;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error : "No overload for method 'Show' takes '3' arguments". Any idea why?

**EDIT:** Here is a step by step using a new application to demonstrate the issue:

1. As you can see, I am using VS2008

[image]

2.Visual C# > Smart Device Project

[image]

3. Target platform: Windows CE  -  .NET Compact Framework Version 3.5

[image]

4. I create a button = `button1` & a label = `label1`

[image]

5. Here is the code I entered, but the error persists

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to let us know exactly what `MessageBox` is in the context of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is in the .NET Compact framework there is no overload which takes 3 arguments, as the error says.

You can use this:

```
DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "text",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

Comment: In any other non compact framework application I am able to do what I did, it worked your way! Thanks!

Comment: Ya there are loads of overloads which work in the Full framework which don't work in the compact framework.

Answer (score 1):

One plausible explanation is that you are targetting .net 1 which, for the compact framework, only has a [single `MessageBox.Show` method that accepts a single parameter of type `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.71).aspx).

Support in the [compact framework for the overload that you seek to use was added in .net 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0x49kd7z(v=vs.80).aspx), at least as far as I can tell from the documentation.

You state in comments that you are using .net 3.5. In which case the only sane conclusion to draw would be that `MessageBox` must be something other than `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`, since that class, in .net 3.5, on the compact framework, has the overload you seek to call.

Finally, @CathalMF asserts that the overload really is not present in the compact framework. Maybe the documentation is just wrong!

Comment: That should be in the question. Also in the question should be enough information for us to reproduce what you report. Since the method you seek to call is supported in the .net 3.5  compact framework, what you claim in the question does not add up. How can we reproduce what you report?

Comment: @CathalMF According to the doc that I linked to it is

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's a link to the Full Framework doc.

Comment: @CathalMF At the bottom it says supported on Windows CE

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok I missed that. I guess their documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("my text", "title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, 
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f5f71b1-3b3c-40e1-a863-24cb2b608c42/messagebox-with-ok-and-cancel-buttons?forum=netfxcompact)

Answer (score -3):

you have to use the `System.Windows.Forms`

```
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dialogresult = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "text", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

Comment: I am using `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult`

Comment: just copy and past my answer in your solution and try it

Comment: Then you are making some other mistake there is nothing related MessageBox